# Using the $content variable in Drupal

Tags: drupal, themes, drupal-7

While in *page.tpl.php*, what's the difference between the two?

```
render($page['content']);
render($content);
```

Or am I just looking at this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 6 used `$content` to display the body content, and Drupal 7 prefers `$page['content']`.

See the API documentation for [page.tpl.php (Drupal 6)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php/6)  and [page.tpl.php (Drupal 7)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php).

I'd stick with the preferred method for the version you're using to ensure you get the expected results.

Comment: I see, so one of them is simply a carryover from the previous version. That pretty much settles it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the same, because `$content` is in the array `$page['content']`.

Also, do `print_r($page['content']);` to see whats going on

Comment: So this is also the same then: `<?php print $content; ?>` Is that correct?

Comment: print() is the same as echo()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php
http://php.net/manual/es/function.echo.php
print_r — Prints human-readable information about a variable

Answer (score 0):

It is printing the label because you have not hidden the label in the content fields admin area.  To hide it, go to structure -> content types -> manage display -> label (hidden).